# Wordpress Permalink/URL Rewriting to something other than index.php

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, wordpress

This may not be possible...

But, it's a simple question, I have requirement to make this rewrite rule work:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    "^Images/awaiting.png", "plugins/My_Plugin/Images/awaiting.png","top"
);
```

It doesn't, and having read around on here, the reason is that the Redirect part has to start with `index.php`.

Fair enough, but is there any way around this **without** modifying `htaccess`? I am trying to achieve this entirely within the plugin code so no code modifications are required by the client after downloading the plugin.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking...

Comment: All the default rewrite rules seem to start with `index.php`, so it may not be possible.  But if the [Codex example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Example) always holds, you might be able to rewrite to `/wp-content/plugins....` (assuming your install's in the root directory; if it's not, you may have to prepend its path)

Comment: FWIW, you might have more luck on the WordPress stackexchange, since this is very specific to WordPress